# How can i make this div match the size of the other column?

Tags: html, css

I have this table with Peoples names and several weeks with each week a selection of football teams, i need to make it so the column with all the names in it is the same as the weekly columns but the weekly columns keeps going large unless i specifically give it a height but i don't know exactly how big i just want it to get bigger as the more entry's there are to it.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Names</div>
            <div class="row">Bob</div>
            <div class="row">Alex</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
            <div class="row">Steve</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 demo">
            <div class="col-xs-3 item">
                <div class="row bg-blue">Week 1</div>
                <div class="row">Man C</div>
                <div class="row">Arsen</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 item">
                <div class="row bg-blue">Week 2</div>
                <div class="row">Man C</div>
                <div class="row">Arsen</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 item">
                <div class="row bg-blue">Week 3</div>
                <div class="row">Man C</div>
                <div class="row">Arsen</div>
                <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 4</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 5</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 6</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 7</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 8</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 9</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 10</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 11</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 12</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 item">
            <div class="row bg-blue">Week 13</div>
            <div class="row">Man C</div>
            <div class="row">Arsen</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
            <div class="row">Chel</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  


    <br /><br />



  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dragend.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(function() {
      var BODY = $("body"),
          container = $(".demo"),
          pageElements;

      $(window).on("ready resize", function(event) {

        var width = $(this).width(),
            itemsInPage = 1;

        if (width > 1000) {
          itemsInPage = 5
        } else if (width > 600) {
          itemsInPage = 4;
        } else if (width > 400) {
          itemsInPage = 2;
        }

        container.dragend({
          pageContainer: "#container",
          itemsInPage: itemsInPage,
          pageClass: "item",
          afterInitialize: function() {
            this.container.style.visibility = "visible";
          }
        });

      });

    });

  </script>
```

Here is the css im using:

```
.demo {
    background: #457;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    height:50%;
}

.item {
    background: #354;
}

.item:nth-child(2n+0) {
    background: #333;
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://olli460.com/fc/index.php?page=test

Answer (score 0):

your inline style is overwriting bootstrap style `col-xs-3`:

`<div class="col-xs-3 item" style="margin: 0px; float: left; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; padding: 0px; display: block; height: 320px; width: 171px;">`

Try to remove the `width: 171px;` or add it to your name col.

[image]

Comment: Thanks i added that code you provided and it's made the divs not as tall but it still doesn't shrink to the size of the content: http://olli460.com/fc/index.php?page=test